# Bivariate normal distribution in polar coordinates with unknown correlation between the variables.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Consider the problem of finding the dist. of $\theta$ after changing a two dimensional normal distribution to polar coordinates where both variables are standard.

Using transformation theorem I get;

$$f_{R_,\theta}(r,\theta)=f_{X_{1},X_{2}}(r\cos \theta,r\sin\theta)r$$

which by characterisation thm. of multivariate normally distributed r.v's is

$$\frac{r}{2\pi(1-\rho^2)}\exp{\left({\frac{\rho r^2\sin(2\theta)}{(1-\rho^2)}-\frac{r^2}{2(1 -\rho^2)}}\right)}$$

The answer should be $\frac{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}{2\pi(1-\rho \sin(2\theta))}$ but I can't seem to get this. Any ideas what I do wrong or what one should do in order to get this?

Comment: You need to integrate in $r$, to convert the joint pdf of $(r,\theta)$ into the marginal pdf of $\theta$. (I'm also pretty sure your answer is not correct, because when $\rho=0$ you should have that $\theta$ is uniform.)

Comment: @Ian I cant see why.. :/

Comment: In regards to which part?

Comment: @Ian well if $\rho =0$ we get $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ which is uniform. The rest does not depend on $\theta$

Comment: Er, oh, my mistake, sorry about that. Anyway, yeah, integrate the joint pdf over $r$ to get the marginal pdf of $\theta$.

Comment: @Ian ill try...

Comment: It's not hard, actually: roll the constants (including the $\theta$ dependence) together to see $are^{-br^2}$ and now think about how to integrate it.. Then plug back in what these "constants" were.

Comment: I suggest to double-check that expression for the joint density function. It doesn't seem to match [equations (1) and (2) on the Wolfram Mathworld page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BivariateNormalDistribution.html) even after you make the obviously necessary substitutions for the mean and standard deviation of each variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comment by Ian;

Integrate in $r$, to convert the joint pdf of $(r,θ)$ into the marginal pdf of $θ$. (I'm also pretty sure your answer is not correct, because when $ρ=0$ you should have that $θ$ is uniform.)